# Is there a way to "watch" tags or groups of tags, other than an RSS feed of them?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I'm thinking something on the site, similar to the way you can star questions. You should be able to star tags or groups of tags and when something new happens in that set (an edit to a question or answer, a new answer to an existing question, or a new question), you get notified on the site.

Yes, you can use an RSS feed, but if I were to do that, my RSS feeds would probably triple. I would like to be notified on-site of events such as these.

Comment: Wait! You have trouble organizing your RSS feeds, and SO should solve that for you?

Comment: I don't want this in my RSS feed. I want things I need to know about ASAP in my RSS feed - very few things on Stack Overflow fall into that category. I might not care about updates in a watched tag or tags until I visit Stack Overflow, and I should be able to get notified when I visit the site.

Comment: Conversely, some of us who use RSS for non-urgent things might like an email notification for new posts on a tag we consider urgent. I’d at least like an email option. Is there one? Don’t see it.

Comment: this is now implemented: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/276202

Comment: @glS no, it's not. There are no notifications for tags.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Yes, it is implemented. You can organize groups of tags into a filter. When there are new questions, a little red dot appears next to the filter. It's not an inbox notification, but the implementation handles my needs. I've done this on both Stack Overflow and Software Engineering. Between tag watching and custom filter lists, what I asked for has been done.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask you can get email notifications for all new questions in the watched tags as well

Comment: @glS you mean filters on se.com?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I guess that's what they are called yes. They don't provide in-site notifications but you do get notified (by email) of all new questions on watched tags

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask The ones I use are not the ones on stackexchange.com. Although those exist, I use the ones on each individual site.

Answer (score 3):

You can hover a tag and then click subscribe. Every time a new question is asked you'll be notified by email.