# Plans to upgrade "Featured On Meta" sidebar widget to use Stacks design components?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, sidebar, community-bulletin

I'm wondering if there are any plans to modify the "Featured On Meta" sidebar widget to use the same styling as other widgets such as a recently launched "Tag Watching" widgets. When "Tag Watching" first came out, I noticed that the styling of the widget did not match the existing "Featured On Meta" box above it. This was referenced in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312241/299995) in the announcement post. However, I have now realized that the "Tag Watching" widget is using a component from the ["Stacks"](https://stackoverflow.design/) design system. And if you go to [this page](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/sidebar-widgets#alternative-colors), you will see that there is a mock-up of how the "Featured On Meta" box should look with the same sidebar component.

I'm sorry if this is something that was planned. But it is also possible that this is something that was overlooked and needs to be implemented for that widget.

Since pictures speak louder than words, here is a screenshot of how the featured box should look using the updated design:

[image: sidebar widget]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the recent design change, "Featured On Meta" sidebar widget using the Stacks design components.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: sidebar]

Comment: I dislike it already ( ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ )