# How to get notified about new questions on tags in new UI?

Tags: support, tags, notifications, email, subscription

There will be a [new system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching) for watching tags, but until that's implemented, I seem to not be able to follow tags the old way. Since that's the only way that currently sends out mails, it should still be possible. But how to do it?

Comment: @Glorfindel Wouldn't it be better to have a proper answer for this, either here or there, than some comment linking to an answer that is really a question with the answer in the comments?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I'll reopen the older question and add a CW answer.