# Help center still has the guidance about old Favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, help-center, tag-watching

It has been a while Favorite tags were <s>added Big Brother eye</s>  changed to Watched tags and some user interface improvements were added. (['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/357396)) Our faq is [also updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/357396) to reflect that change. But the related help center still has guidance about old Favorite tags and ignored tags, and uses outdated instructions, terminology, and imagery.

Look at [How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics).

> [image: Image from help center article showing old favorite tags]

Can this be updated to reflect the new change?

Comment: I've mentioned that in an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317114/295232) in the question where this feature was launched.

Comment: Might be helpful to consolidate/ dupe-close this to [Update Help Center page for "finding interesting topics"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336232), which mentions this in addition to other much needed updates on that Help Center page.