# Help page for watching tags is out of date

Tags: bug, help-center, tag-watching

The help center has a page on managing favorite and ignored tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics

However the interface and some of the terminology around this feature changed completely a few months ago: ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching)

The help page no longer actually depicts the current process accurately, and uses outdated descriptions, instructions, and terminology. It ought to be updated.

Comment: I've mentioned that in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317114/295232) already, and I'm pretty sure somebody else asked a question about this as well.

Comment: Ah, found it: [Help center still has the guidance about old Favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318437/help-center-still-has-the-guidance-about-old-favorite-tags)