# Update Help Center page for "finding interesting topics"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, help-center

The [Help Center page on finding interesting topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) is hopelessly outdated.

Please update it (and potentially others) to:

- Remove mentions of the defunct email subscription feature:

> *If you'd like to be notified of new activity within a certain tag, you can **subscribe via email** or RSS by...*

- Explain custom filters, which go completely unmentioned throughout the entire Help Center
- Replace references to "favorite" tags with "watched" tags
- Update the references to defunct UI, e.g.:

> *You can also toggle a tag between normal, favorite, or ignored by mousing over the tag and clicking the star icon.*

- Replace the images with modern equivalents:

  - Eg. Replace:

  > [image: Legacy tag banner pop-up]

  - With:
    [image: Modern tag banner pop-up]

Also, replace the link used in

> For more tips, visit the [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) page and click on "advanced tips".

with a direct link to [the relevant Help Center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) instead.

---

Prompted by [this user request](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1658/98) I would have loved to close as duplicate of a help page.

Comment: The CMs have been reviewing some of the help center pages recently, so I'm adding the [status-review] tag so that this can be added to the list of pages for us to look at.

Comment: Oh wow, those outdated tips have been up for another 2y+? Wow. o_o

Comment: The examples are for a particular site. Is this only about that site or is it generally applicable? Can you add an indication to your question? For example, does *"potentially others"* refer to other help center pages or to other sites? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Features are mentioned on that page that do not exist on SE anymore. It's the same on all network sites. Personally, I think that's clear enough from the question as is.

Comment: I stumbled across this after almost spinning up my own request to ask for the same updates/ changes to this particular page; I can't believe this request has been sitting dormant for nearly 2 years. The state of the Help Center has _got_ to get a bump in priority; it's ridiculous that the site's own documentation is outdated enough to not reference major features like filters.

Comment: An MSO post that mentions the "favorite tags" phrasing needing an update: [Favorite tags and up to date help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381701/1478931)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated the [linked Help Center article](/help/interesting-topics) (located at `/help/interesting-topics`) network-wide to address all the issues you mentioned. I basically rewrote a bunch of the article (including outdated feature names and descriptions of the UI), updated the screenshots, added some clarifications to various sections, and added a new section on custom filters.

While I was editing the body of the article, I also changed the title to: "**How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?**". (It was originally titled "How do I find topics I'm interested in?" – presumably referencing "interesting tags", the original name of the feature now known as [tag watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/335251).) I figured I'd avoid changing the title completely – but at least now the title more accurately reflects what this Help Center page is about.