# Markdown formatting problems in the Help Center article "How do I search?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, markdown, help-center

In the Help Center article [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), there seem to be a few Markdown formatting problems:

1. In the section "Boolean Operators", the subheading "OR operator" is not rendered correctly: a space is missing in "###OR Operator" between "#" and "OR".
2. In the section "Miscellaneous Operators", the bullet points are not rendered as bullet points; instead everything is in a single paragraph, with bullets separated by hyphens.
3. The spacing above the section titled "Deleted Posts (requires 10,000 reputation)" seems to be incorrect.
4. I'm not sure, but I think in the section "Range Operators", the words "score", "answers" and "views" are intended to be in bold formatting, but it is currently rendered as follows:

   > To search for only questions that fall within a particular range for **score**, number of **answers**, or number of **views**, you can enter an upper or lower parameter, or a range.
5. While we are at it, I'll just add that in the section "Dates", the three bullet points under "Absolute dates" use an en dash "–" to separate the example, but the two bullet points under "Relative dates" use a hyphen "-" for the same. It would be better to use an en dash in all the cases.

Comment: I'd really like to see some more emphasis be put on improving the Help Center... or even just [keeping it up to date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336232). [Quite a bit of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=update+is%3Aq+%28+%5Bfeature-request%5D+OR+%5Bbug%5D+%29+%5Bhelp-center%5D+closed%3A0+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bsupport%5D) could use some love.

Comment: @zcoop98: A few of the requests in your second link are very minor, and a few were already implemented years ago... I did manage to go through some of that list, though. (And I'm working on the one that basically involves rewriting a whole Help Center page...)

Comment: @V2Blast Awesome, thank you <3. I just feel like the help center gets neglected sometimes, even though we try to direct new folks there all the time. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting these issues! I've now updated the Help Center page [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) network-wide (and [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), which has a site-specific override of the page to mention Collectives-related search parameters) to address all these issues. Let me know if there's anything I've missed.

Comment: Other than a few missing full stops, everything has been fixed :)