# Haven't Received Any Email on Watched Tags Ever

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email, tag-watching

I wonder if this is a broken functionality just on the stack exchange that I'm part of. I've subscribed to ethereum.stackexchange.com and I have three watched tags `solidity` `parity` and `ethereum-classic` and I've been watching them since mid-October 2018 but I have yet to receive any emails about new questions asked with those tags in it. Checking those tags manually shows that they are being used for asking questions on the site.

I guess the email functionality isn't working? Not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Tag Watching does not send any email, it's just a different name for Favorite Tags, which means it adds a background color to the questions having this tag in questions list. There used to be a way to **subscribe** to tags, which sent emails, SE removed that option.

Comment: You can subscribe to an RSS feed for a tag. Well, at least on stats.stackexchange.com you can, so perhaps that would do what you want another way.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We're going to be revamping the experience of both setting up notifications and watching tags (this is in the works), but at best you can expect to get an email with *unread* inbox notifications fired from watched tags every few hours, depending on how you set it up. This means, if you read the inbox notification on the site, you're not going to see it delivered.

If you want real-time notifications, pulling a feed is your best bet. We can't send one email per, or any more than the combined *unread notification* digest, or we'd end up sending considerably more email than some providers would like. Additionally, it could create a *ton* of inadvertent noise.

It's not a bug, it's intentionally designed that way, albeit notifications are wonky and something we're still working out.

Comment: Bad design. You removed a key feature of subscribing to a single tag and gave no simple alternative.

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure what you're talking about @ShadowWizard - you can easily watch a single tag.

Comment: Watching a tag does not let me get emails with new questions posted with this tag, that is the whole point here. In the old tag popup, there was "subscribe" link letting us actually subscribe to the tag and get emails. This is gone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Have you [read how the two will be integrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/50049)? You'll be able to get notifications and if unread, they'll be delivered to you via email.

Comment: **Will**, in some unknown date in the future. So why didn't you just wait until this is ready before releasing it all together? It's like serving half baked cake. No?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I like the change, it look neater and more fit with other design changes. But I don't like features being removed for months. (Same happened with pasting image via URL for example, luckily that feature was missing "only" for few weeks.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because sometimes we just have to do things in a certain way because of the way things work, is the only explanation I can give you. We don't intentionally go looking to annoy people, but when you're re-rigging a bunch of stuff to knock down debt, well, it  .. happens. Sorry about that, best I can say.

Comment: Also, it's _extremely_ easy to be very critical when you don't know the scope of what folks are dealing with. Metaphors like 'serving a half baked cake' aren't helpful, in fact they're actively unhelpful, it assumes we're not smart enough to realize it's not optimal. Just _sayin'_.

Comment: No worry. I know you didn't do it in order to annoy me, or anyone in particular. But still, seeing cheese **re**moved is more annoying than seeing cheese just moved, which is expected.

Comment: So let us know the whole scope, I don't see why it should be a secret? About half baked cakes, it can happen for example when people are in hurry to serve the cake to a demanding customer, so they decide to give at least something. Don't know if time limits/deadlines are the case here too and I do not try to imply you're not smart enough, just saying how it feels like as that customer. I do like the half part which is baked, and expect to see the cake fully baked. :-)