# Different behavior when adding nonexistent tag to watched tags from sidebar vs profile settings

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, error-message, tag-watching

From questions list (error shown if no such tag):

> [image]

From settings page (no error):

> [image]

Could you show an error if user is trying to add a nonexistent tag from profile settings page?

Comment: Related [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312208/312043) about tag synonyms.