# stackexchange.com filter says 'Favorite tags' instead of 'Watched tags'

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stackexchange.com, tag-watching, wording

[Back in July 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/351462), 'favorite tags' were renamed to 'watched tags'. However, the wording was never updated on stackexchange.com when [filtering questions by favorite tag](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags).

[image: View questions based on your favorite tags across the Stack Exchange network]

Comment: Not only in the filters: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317114/295232